# Java ImageIO.read causing OSX to hang

Tags: java, image, macos, png

I'm having to do some bits with reading in an image on Mac OSX, however it seems to hang when calling ImageIO.read ( File ). No stack trace seems to appear either, it literally just hangs. Was wondering if anyone else had experienced this problem?

I've been successful in writing an image, just seems to be a problem with reading. Working with .png files.

OSX 10.9.2
Java 1.7.40

Comment: I've not had any issues recently

Comment: same here with .bmp, how did you solved it ? img = (BufferedImage)(new ImageIcon(path).getImage()); also hangs

Comment: And I'm from 2019.

Mac OS X **10.14.5** (_Mojave_), Oracle JDK **1.8.0_192** and also [JetBrains Runtime](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/JBR/JetBrains+Runtime) **1.8.0_202**.

Comment: One more remark: whenever `ImageIO.read()` hangs, `java.awt.Toolkit.getImage()` hangs, too, so this second call can't be used as a workaround.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395318

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found in the end was to do the following on the mac

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)seleniumCommonHandler.getCurrentSeleniumDriver())
.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read( scrFile );
```

For some reason the ImageIO no matter what I tried could not read the image directly from the file system. By using this approach I managed to get around the issue.